# Cab PHP create an Input field?

Tags: php, wordpress, input

I'm trying to create a cookie for a web page. The cookie value will vary based on the users name. Does PHP have an input type function? I just want to add an input field to the page an then the PHP will use that to define the users name for the page. I have the create cookie code, just can't figure out how to get the name from the screen and insert it to the cookie code. Appreciate any suggestions. This is on a WP website.

Comment: `echo` is the function you're looking for. 

Answer (score 0):

Not natively because php does not execute in browser, it executes on your server, but it can be used to write an HTML input.

The syntax would look something like this:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="myinput">';
```

or

```
?>
  <input type="text" name="myinput">
<?php
```

You would then use a form post, CURL, or AJAX function to send the data back to the server where a second PHP script would process the input.

That said, it would help to post your create cookie code, since you may not even need to send it back to the server, but just handle it all in the browser using Javascript in which case your submit button only needs to pass the input to a Javascript function instead of posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for? 
Here it just takes the value user input from the browser and set it as a cookie

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){
        setcookie('setcookie_name',$_POST['name']); // setting cookie 
    }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input name="name" value="" placeholder="Enter your name" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```